# Probability In a Bridge Deal - Different Ways of Computation

Tags: probability

In a bridge deal, what is the probability that West has four spades, two hearts, four diamonds and three clubs?

My strategy is as follows.

If we consider alone the West player, there are ${52 \choose 13}$ ways to distribute $13$ cards to him, and in the case that he has four spades, two hearts, four diamonds and three clubs, we just choose a corresponding number of cards from each of spades, hearts, diamonds and clubs. Therefore the probability is
$\frac{{13 \choose 4}{13 \choose 2}{13 \choose 4}{13 \choose 3}}{{52 \choose 13}}$.

The book suggests that it should be $\frac{\frac{13!}{4!2!4!3!}}{{52 \choose 13}}$.

I know that $\frac{13!}{4!2!4!3!}$ is the number of ways of arranging four spades, two hearts, four diamonds and three clubs, only considering which suit a card is in, but I think what should be taken into account is that for each suit, the $13$ cards are all distinct, so you cannot simply count the number of arrangements. Can anyone explain where I was wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: What book? Is that exactly what the book said?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's Applied Combinatorics 6th Edition by Alan Tucker. The book just gave an answer without explanation, and I guess the wrong answer is one of the errata.

Comment: Yes, see: http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~tucker/ApCombcorrect.html

Comment: I just wanted to clarify.. the denominator should not be C(52, 13) because we are not looking for only 1 player being dealt 13 cards but rather 4 players being dealt 13 cards therefore, the total number of ways a 52-card deck can be dealt is: 52!/(13!)^4